# SampEn algorithm Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, entropy

I need a simple algorithm for SampEn . [this](http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35784-sample-entropy/content/SampEn.m) is matlab script which I cannot understand (script doesnt matter I just need to understand the alg):

```
function saen = SampEn( dim, r, data, tau )

if nargin < 4, tau = 1; end
if tau > 1, data = downsample(data, tau); end

N = length(data);
correl = zeros(1,2);
dataMat = zeros(dim+1,N-dim);     %why N-dim ???
for i = 1:dim+1
    dataMat(i,:) = data(i:N-dim+i-1);   %1 statement
end

for m = dim:dim+1           %why not 1:dim+1 ????
    count = zeros(1,N-dim);   %2 statement
    tempMat = dataMat(1:m,:);   %3 statement

    for i = 1:N-m

        dist = max(abs(tempMat(:,i+1:N-dim) - repmat(tempMat(:,i),1,N-dim-i)));    %4 statement

        D = (dist < r);     %5 statement   

        count(i) = sum(D)/(N-dim);    %6 statement
    end

    correl(m-dim+1) = sum(count)/(N-dim);    %7 statement
end

saen = log(correl(1)/correl(2));
end
```

I need to understand it so I can write it in python.

what does each for loop and their statements mean(aka statements that I commented)?

I know this is not a good question but Im stuck here please F1

Comment: Do you have some example data to be passed to the function? That would help.

Comment: Yes... there is plenty of data on the internet.

Comment: need guidance ? there are many search engines on the web like google,yahoo,bing , etc where you can search for something . if still have problems please ask

Comment: I don't need guidance, I know how search engines work, but this isn't about me. Are you processing a time series image?

Comment: @ElijahRockers ofc. if you cant find data just use lists like [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3] . SampEn or more generally ApEn Evaluates for patterns to recur!